# How to print non repeating elements with original list

Tags: python

given a  list of integers nums, return a list of all the element but the repeating number should not be printed more than twice

example

input: `nums = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5]`

output: `[1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5]`

Comment: That output still prints numbers twice!? Regardless of that: what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible implementation using `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import islice, groupby, chain

nums = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5]

output = (islice(g, 2) for _, g in groupby(nums))
output = list(chain.from_iterable(output))
print(output) # [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

You can replace `2` in `islice(g, 2)` to tune the max repeats you want.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and I guess most straight forward way to use unique collections is with a `set`:

```
list(set(nums)) -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The downside of this approuch is that `set`s are unordered. And we cannot really depend on how the list will be sorted after the conversion.

If order is important in your case you can do this:

```
list(dict.fromkeys(nums))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`dict`s are ordered since python3 came out, and their keys are unique. So with this small trick we get a list of the unique keys of a dictionary, but still maitain the original order!

Comment: hey, thanks but i need output as input: nums = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5] output: [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,5] I need output which contains dublices repeated two times only (not three times) with the original list,